# Calling a C function from R

Tags: c, r

I would like to wrap calls to any one of these C functions within an R function:

```
char *sendpraat (void *display, const char *programName, long timeOut, const char *text);
wchar_t *sendpraatW (void *display, const wchar_t *programName, long timeOut, const wchar_t *text);
```

I can build the source code fine:

```
$ R CMD SHLIB -o pRaat.so sendpraat.c 
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -    fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c sendpraat.c -o sendpraat.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -    multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o pRaat.so sendpraat.o -    F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

But I cause R to crash when I call the loaded function:

```
dyn.load("pRaat.so")
.Call("sendpraat",
as.integer(1),
as.character("Praat"),
as.integer(0),
as.character("Create Sound as pure tone... tone 1 0 0.4 44100 440 0.2 0.01 0.01"),
PACKAGE="pRaat")

*** caught segfault ***
address 0x0, cause 'unknown'
```

Could it be the (void *) that I sypply that is causing this? It's not used by the underlying function on my plattform (OSX).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `.Call()` interfaces takes and returns `SEXP` objects, so your interface is wrong.
You could try the older `.C()` though it is discouraged for new projects. Note that you will need convert your function there too -- maybe time to revisit some of the examples in [Writing   R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)?